# Not able to link HDF5 path in CMake configuration

Tags: cmake, hdf5

I'm trying to create make files of C++ code on a server doing

```
cmake ../
```

and I get the error

```
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found version "1.10.7")
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:180 (message):
  HDF5 support was requested, but no HDF5 library was found on this system
```

I have installed HDF5 in `/home/directory/` so I have HDF5 include and library files in

```
/home/directory/include

/home/directory/lib
```

I've tried to add in CMakeLists.txt the following lines:

```
 set(HDF5_LIBRARIES "/home/directory/")

 set(HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES "/home/directory/")

 set(HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/directory/")

 set(HDF5_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/directory/")
```

But still getting the error.
I've also tried to export HDF5_ROOT=/home/directory/ without success.

The error come from the following lines in the code:

```
  if (HDF5_FOUND)
            target_include_directories(soft PUBLIC ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
            target_link_libraries(soft PUBLIC ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
    else (HDF5_FOUND)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "HDF5 support was requested, but no HDF5 library was found on this system")
    endif (HDF5_FOUND)
```

Any help?

Using CMake 3.19.3 and hdf5-1.10.7

Comment: You may need to add `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to your command line to specify the location of the HDF5 CMake config files, e.g. `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/directory`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @vre just tried but still not working :(

Comment: Did you cleaned the CMake cache, i.e. deleted CMakeCache.txt in the build directory before rerunning CMake?

Comment: Which CMake version are you actually using? 8.4.0 doesn't exist to my knowledge. CMake 2.8.4 does, though. It is a pretty old version, I'd recommend testing a newer one. https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/cmakebuild.html may help you as well. It states CMake 3.2.2 as minimum version.

Comment: Sorry I reported the g++ version. CMake 3.19.3. I edited in the question

Comment: @vre yes I've cleaned it...

Just for adding infos: I'm using g++ and cmake installed in custom folder since I don't have root access on the server. Don't know if this can be a problem.
I have however set the right compiler with export 

CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++

and used the right version of cmake from .../cmake-3.19.3/bin/cmake

Comment: A typical sequence to find HDF5 looks like `set(HDF5_DIR /home/directory/cmake/hdf5)`  (you need to point this variable to the directory that contains the `hdf5-config.cmake` file) and a subsequent call to `find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS C CXX CXX_HL Tools NO_MODULE REQUIRED)` By doing so you use the CMake configuration files provided by your HDF5 installation. HDF5_DIR variable may be provided on the command line to.

Comment: @vre I don't have 'hdf5-config.cmake' cause I installed hdf5 like [link](https://fossies.org/linux/hdf5/release_docs/INSTALL) point 2 quick installation. Can it be a problem?

Comment: Then the sequence is somewhat different. `set(HDF5_ROOT /home/directory)` followed by `set(HDF5_NO_FIND_PACKAGE_CONFIG_FILE TRUE)` followed by `find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS C CXX CXX_HL Tools)` . That way the FindHDF5 module from your CMake installation is used. You may add the `REQUIRED` keyword if your program cannot run without HDF5 to make CMake stop then.

Comment: I partially solved. I was missing 2 thigs:
- using the flag '--enable-cxx' when installing hdf5
- using '-DHDF5_ROOT' flag when running cmake

But now I have another problem when running the biuld of the program.

    /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found    



The point is that is looking in    '/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6'     instead of    '/somepath/lib64/libstdc++.so.6'   , where I have installed the new g++ compiler. I have tried linking    '-DLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/somepath/lib64/'    when using CMake command  without success.

Comment: Solved with
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/somepath/lib64/

Thanks to all for th precious help :)